# Creating radio button

Tags: wxwidgets

I am working with radio buttons in wxWidgets and I am having a problem initializing the size of the button and its coordinates on the frame.

The following code creates the radio button, but it does not give it the correct size and starting coordinates (wxPoint and wxSize do not work).

My question is: How do I implement correctly wxSize and wxPoint in this case?

Thanks,

```
        //Units Radio Box
    wxString choices[] = { "Metric (mm)","Imperial (in.)" };
    int Num_Choices = 2;

wxRadioBox * Units;

    Units = new wxRadioBox(this,
                            wxID_ANY, 
                            _T("Input Units"),
                            wxPoint(-20,-25),
                            wxSize(20,20), 
                            Num_Choices,
                            choices,
                            1,
                            wxRA_SPECIFY_COLS,
                            wxDefaultValidator,
                            _T("Input Units"));
```

Comment: First of all, this is not a radio button (`wxRadioButton`), but a radio box. Second, what exactly do you want to achieve by specifying negative position? Third, and most importantly, what do you mean by "do not work", i.e. what actually happens?

Comment: Running the application shows the radio box, however, the box occupies the entire frame and not a specified size. Also, I can't explicitly define where it should originate on the frame using wxPoint. The negative units were just for trial, I tried positive int values, but nothing happened.

Comment: @CivilSigma, wjy not just use sizers? There are a lot of tutorials, documentation and an official samples...

Comment: Also, I presume there is more controls on the frame?

Comment: @Igor no there was not, i think that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in `EVT_SIZE` description of [wxFrame documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.3/classwx_frame.html), it resizes its *only* child to fill the entire client area by default. This is something that is very convenient in the common case when you have a `wxPanel` as the single child of the frame, but obviously not so much if you want to have just a radio box.

To fix this, define your own `wxEVT_SIZE` handler doing nothing. Or, maybe even simpler, just create another window (that could be a `wxStaticText` without label, making it effectively invisible).

Of course, using absolute position and sizes is not going to work in any case because of the differences between platforms, displays DPI etc, so it's **strongly** not recommended to do this. Use sizers for the layout instead of at the very least use dialog units instead of values in pixels.

Comment: Thank you. I created a test wxButton and then my wxRadioBox element updated to the expected size. To clarify my understanding: any button/item created is the "child" of the wxFrame? Can I ask you what dialog units are (is it wxDialog) ?

Comment: Sorry if this is basic, as I am just starting with wxWidgets and reading the documentation can be a bit overwhelming. but should I be adding buttons to a panel or the original frame?  My understanding is that I create a wxFrame, and then I can add to it buttons etc. But, I just saw a tutorial where you can add a Panel to the wxFrame, and then add buttons to the panel. Is that a better design choice?

Comment: Any child window created with `wxFrame` as `parent` argument of its ctor is its child. As for the dialog units, please see the documentation for `ConvertDialogToPixels()`. Once again, though, this is _not_ what you should use in the first place. Ideally there should be no hard-coded values, neither in dialog units nor pixels.

Comment: @CivilSigma, just to clarify things - using wxPanel is completely optional. But it is very convenient if you want to have a TAB-bing to work and not not handle the TAB key yourself, which might be tricky, especially if you have many controls and some are disabled/hidden/read-only.. Also, as Vadim said - you should start looking into using sizers. Check the documentation about wxSizer and its descendant and also look at the samples.